# What would Google-Docs-like version history look like using Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, prisma

After some initial research, I'm trying to determine a scalable solution for implementing Google-Docs-like version history for Postgres tables. The difficulty is that these tables have one-to-many and self-referential one-to-many relationships, so the solutions from my research look like they would require creating lots of additional data. As an example, let's say I have the following tables.

```
table A {
    id         string          
    name       string          
    created_at date         
    updated_at date                 
}

table B {
    id          string  
    title       string 
    text_data   json (used in a rich text editor)
    b_id        string?
    a_id        string
    created_at  date 
    updated_at  date       
}
```

Table A has a one-to-many relationship with table B. Table B can have a one-to-many relationship with itself (imagine something like nested children).

The goal is a Google-Docs-like "version history" where changes to either A or B are recorded, and a previous/historical version of A or B can be restored.

In researching, I found the "History Table" pattern, but have not been able to find what that implementation would look like with one-to-many and self-referential one-to-many relationships. Do both tables get their own history tables (e.g. `A_History` and `B_History`) where the history tables are related?

Another method is to use the current tables, but to add new columns that can be used to determine the current version. Something like `start_date` and `end_date` where if `end_date` is `null` then that row is the current version.

But in either case, it seems like the amount of data would be huge, considering any update to A or B needs to be tracked. Prisma is being used to define the database schema and as an ORM.

What would a scalable solution for this look like using Postgres?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Temporal_Extensions is what you are looking for I believe

Comment: @RichardHuxton -- Ah, I mentioned I was using Prisma but wasn't explicit in saying that I had come across temporal tables, but Prisma (nor any other ORM I've come across) currently doesn't support them.

Comment: If you want ORM support for this sort of thing I suspect you'll be writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there are 2 main approaches that you can take to solve this.

**1. Storing full history of all rows in A and B in history tables**
When somebody updates a row in B the now old version of that row will get inserted into B_History and the new version into B. This will produce a lot of duplicate data and probably be pretty storage intensive.

**2. Storing differences between versions**
Same as one above but instead of storing the whole version of the record each time you store the differences between individual versions. You could think of this as git diffs in a file between individual commits.
This should reduce storage demands but you will have to calculate the diffs and when you want to roll back to a previous version (or even just show the previous version to the user) you have to re-apply the diffs one by one. (If you want to go from version X to X-3 you have to to X -> X-1 -> X-2 -> X-3, each arrow representing re-applying a diff to a version of the record)

Storing the history in one table and the current versions in another one makes it so that the speed of querying for a current version is not affected by how many historic versions you have stored, this would not be the case if you have historic and current versions in the same table and use the start_date - end_date approach.

I am not sure what scale you are aiming for but partitioning the history tables by created_at and creating appropriate indexes should get you to handle 10s of millions of rows without major issues.

Other things to consider are limiting how many historic versions to store. For example only storing the last X versions or only storing versions created in the last month.
How much granularity of historic versions do you need? If a user spends 5 minutes making continuous edits to a record in B how many historic versions should that produce? Should every time the user "hits save" create a new version or are you fine with having snapshots once per 10 minutes? per hour? per day?

Lastly I don't know what the business meaning of your A-B and B-B relations are but you might have to for example make a history record of all Bs that are related to an A when the A gets changed to capture the full history.